# detect URL with chrome extension when user navigate to the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm creating a chrome extension that can edit in input that exists only in a sepecific page
But when use "matches" in manifest.js file and use this page URL, It only detects the URL when I visit it directly, but when I visit the URL throught navigation from inside the website, It doesn't detect the link
that's what I've tried

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["fill.js"],
            "matches": [
                "https://www.test.com/form"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

I also tried to detect if the user visited this link through navigation I used this solution
manifist.json :

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["fill.js"],
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

fill.js :

```
const INTERVAL = setInterval(function test(){
    let currentPage = document.location.href;

    if (currentPage == 'https://www.test.com/form') {
        const input = document.getElementById('inputTest')
        input.value = "test value"
    }
}, 500)
```

but It also doesn't work untill I visit the URl my self (paste the url in the browser or refresh the page)

so how can I detect the URL? the website I need to add the value to its input is created with react

Comment: Use MutationObserver or `navigation.onnavigate` event and replace `form` with `*` in `matches`